# Search Filters with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

I have a database that is being used to keep track of customer information and equipment.  I've have a working search page that merges all the data together into a readable format.  It is set to displays only one result per page.

I'm trying to add filtering into the search.  This way if you're only searching for the Last Name it won't waste time searching though the equipment database.  It will only search the Last Name field from the Customers table.  I've got that to work the problem is the when the next page is pressed it gets zero results.

I have an idea why its happening.  It's because I'm using isset with checkboxes to do the filters.

```
$SLastName = $_GET['LastName'];
$SFirstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
$SAddress = $_GET['Address'];
$SAP = $_GET['AP'];
$SEquipment = $_GET['Equipment'];
$SEverything = $_GET['Everything'];

if (isset($SLastName)){
        $construct .="(customers.LastName LIKE '%$search_each%')";  
        if (isset($SFirstName)){
        $construct .=" OR (customers.FirstName LIKE '%$search_each%')"; 
        }
        if (isset($SAddress)){
        $construct .=" OR (customers.Address LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SAP)){
        $construct .=" OR (aps.AP LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SEquipment)){
        $construct .=" OR (equipment.ESN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.Manufacturer LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SEverything)){
        $construct .=" OR (customers.Account LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (customers.AlternatePhone LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (customers.Phone LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (routableip.routable_IP LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (unitip.UNITIP_new LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
    }
    else if(isset($SFirstName)){
        $construct .="(customers.FirstName LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        if (isset($SAddress)){
        $construct .=" OR (customers.Address LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SAP)){
        $construct .=" OR (aps.AP LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SEquipment)){
        $construct .=" OR (equipment.ESN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.Manufacturer LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
    }
    else if(isset($SAddress)){
        $construct .="(customers.Address LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        if (isset($SAP)){
        $construct .=" OR (aps.AP LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
        if (isset($SEquipment)){
        $construct .=" OR (equipment.ESN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.Manufacturer LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
    }
    else if(isset($SAP)){
        $construct .="(aps.AP LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        if (isset($SEquipment)){
        $construct .=" OR (equipment.ESN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.Manufacturer LIKE '%$search_each%')";
        }
    }
    else if(isset($SEquipment)){
        $construct .="(equipment.ESN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.WMAC LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.SN LIKE '%$search_each%')
                OR (equipment.Manufacturer LIKE '%$search_each%')";
}
```

The search input page uses checkboxes. The boxes are checked on the submit page to see what fields are set. The set fields determine what the sql is going to be.

Like I said this works fine for finding the first result.

Here the parts of my code pertaining to the pagination.

```
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start']: '';
    $max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);

    if(!$start)
        $start=0; 

//Pagination Starts
        $prev = $start - $per_page;
        $next = $start + $per_page;
        $adjacents = 3;
        $last = $max_pages - 1;

        if($max_pages > 1){   
        //previous button
            if (!($start<=0)) {
                $PrevButton .= "<a href='search.php?
search=$search&submit=Search&start=$prev' class='button Prev1' 
style='vertical-
align:middle'><span>Prev</span></a> ";    
            }
            else{
                $PrevButton .= "<a class='incative' style='vertical-
align:middle'><span>Prev</span></a> ";
            }
            $current =$next;



        //next button
        if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page)){
            $NextButton = "<a href='search.php?
search=$search&submit=Search&start=$next' class='button Next2' 
style='vertical-align:middle'><span>Next</span></a>";
        }
        else {
            $NextButton = "<a class='incative' style='vertical-
align:middle'><span>Next</span></a> ";
        }
        }
```

For example if I search for the Last name Smith.  It will show result 1 of 10.  Then when I press the next button it comes up with the error I have built in for when it does not find any results with the searched keyword.

I think what is happening is when the next button is pressed it changes the GET url to show page 2 but when that happens it looses the value of the search sql because it does not see that $SLastName isset anymore.

I'm lost on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you Right you have to store your search keyword in a session variable and from there you can get keyword in any page and on the basis of that you have to run your query hope this will help you

Comment: TY. Ended up adding the following code.
of course start the session at the top 
    session_start();

I changed the first declaration of 
    $construct = ''; 
changed it to 
    $construct = $_SESSION"["construct"];
Then after all the issets before closing out the if statement I added
    $_SESSION["construct"] = $construct;
I'm using session throughout the site so I can't kill sessions so I added this to the top of the initial search page.
    $_SESSION["construct"] ='';
If I didn't do that then it would save the last set options on the new search.